# AWS RDS MySQL Read Replica option grayed out - only aurora read replica available

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an AWS RDS Mysql 5.6.40 Instance running.  In the past it's been trivial to create a read replica but this particular instance has that option grayed out.

It does however allow the creation of an Aurora read replica - which is **not** what I want.  I specifically want a MySQL 5.6 instance.

[image]

Not sure it's relevant, but I see that the list of DBs shows it as "Instance" whereas in other cases when I have an active read-replica the writer is listed as "Master".

**How can I create a MySQL read-replica?**

FWIW, here's most of the configuration information:

```
Engine version - 5.6.40
DB name - xxxxx_production
License model - General Public License
Option groups - default:mysql-5-6
ARN - arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:***********
Parameter group *******56 (in-sync)
Deletion protection - Disabled
Instance class - db.t2.small
vCPU - 1
RAM - 2 GB
Availability
Master username - *******
IAM db authentication - Not Enabled
Multi AZ - No
Encryption - Not Enabled
Storage type - General Purpose (SSD)
IOPS - -
Storage - 350 GiB
Storage autoscaling - Disabled
```

Comment: Are automatic backups enabled for this db instance?  This looks like a console bug, but the actual bug is that "Create Aurora read replica" should also be grayed out, if you don't have a non-zero retention time for backups. Please confirm.

Comment: That is exactly the problem.  Actually found it yesterday after a lot of searching.  If you'd like to post that as an answer with a link to the relevant doc I'd be happy to accept it!  Not sure that the "create Aurora read replica" part is actually a bug - that seems to use different functionality.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Backups for your instance are currently disabled (retention = 0). Please enable backups before attempting to create a read replica.

Please see our User Guide for more details.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Adding a link to the user guide and an explanation how to do this enablement will improve this answer significantly.

Comment: enabled retention=1, its was working fine.